# Memtest86+: no signal after turning monitor off and on again

Tags: display, memtest86+

I want to run Memtest86+ overnight, but I need to turn my monitor off for that period. Unfortunately, every time I turn the monitor off while Memtest is running, when I turn it back on, it's getting no video signal, so I cannot see any test results. Manual switching the input source on the monitor does not help - when I switch back to my input, the monitor just says again, that there's no signal.

Memtest itself is not frozen, because it reacts to my pressing Esc, and shuts down the computer (pressing any other keys does not show the screen, so I don't know if they are actually working; but I suppose they are, I just cannot see the reaction). Also, I tried turning the monitor off after about a minute of the running test, and turn it back on a few seconds later, and it still got no video signal. And if I keep it on, I can run it for at least an hour without any issue or any memory errors, so it's not caused by the long run.

I'm using the latest available version of Memtest86+, 5.31b, but the same happened with 5.01. Is there any possible workaround, which would let me see the test results? I walked through the settings dialog, but failed to find anything of use.

In case that's relevant, my GPU is nVidia 1660Ti, monitor is NEC PA241W, connected via DisplayPort.

Answer (score 0):

When you turn it off, is that a soft or hard 'off'?

If you remove power entirely from it, then you're reliant on the DisplayPort technology in both the computer & display to be fully spec-compliant. DP should be considered only *theoretically* hot-pluggble, but practically… not.
Soft-off ought to behave better, but you're still reliant on the theoretical compliance of both.

If soft-off is still not working, then you *may* get results by unplugging, wait 5s, re-plug.
If that doesn't work, assume it's your computer which is not compliant. If Memtest86+ is running below the OS, down at 'DOS-type' levels, then I would imagine all the higher-functioning DisplayPort technology is not yet loaded & you'll have to look at another solution, reduce brightness etc.

Comment: Well... I just turn it off by pressing the power button on the front panel of the monitor. I don't know how exactly NEC implemented this button, but I have no other options. The power cable remains connected, of course. When I'm booted into Windows on the same PC with the same config, and I turn the monitor off like this, I can turn it back on later, and it will show me the OS. But with Memtest the same scenario fails for me. I'll try to unplug/plug the DP cable...

Comment: No, unplugging and plugging DP cable didn't help either.